# Pivot table based on pairs

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has the columns `ID, A, A_potential, B, B_potential, ...` Some columns have value, some do not. If A doesn't have value, A_potential doesn't either. I want to only display the columns that have value but also pair the columns with each other. Then loop it so it displays them paired together if they have value.

WHAT I WANT TO SHOW

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="current">30</div> <!--A Value-->
  <div class="potential">35</div> <!--A Potential-->
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="current">50</div> <!--C Value-->
  <div class="potential">75</div> <!--C Potential-->
</div>
```

CURRENT TABLE

```
ID | A  | A_potential | B  | B_potential
--------------------------------------
1  | 35 | 50          | 15 | 30
2  | 0  | 0           | 10 | 70
```

WHAT I WANT TABLE TO LOOK LIKE FOR LOOP PURPOSES

```
ID | Type | Current | Potential
--------------------------
 3 | A    |  35     | 50
 3 | D    |  50     | 75
```

Comment: I do not get the logic that would get you from the current table to the expected output.

Comment: Btw, this seems to be unpivot transformation, not pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION` of queries for each pair.

```
SELECT id, 'A' AS Type, A AS Current, A_Potential AS Potential
FROM yourTable
WHERE A != 0 OR A_Potential != 0
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'B' AS Type, B AS Current, B_Potential AS Potential
FROM yourTable
WHERE B != 0 OR B_Potential != 0
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'C' AS Type, C AS Current, C_Potential AS Potential
FROM yourTable
WHERE C != 0 OR C_Potential != 0
...
```